# Unable to run function with exception

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I have a text file with a list of codes, and I want to write a script that creates folders named after each code and applies a function `ncbiSeq()` to each code that writes a file and stores it in its respective folder.

The script works properly for non-previously exisiting folders.

To avoid an error if the folder named after one of the codes already exists, I tried using `try` and `except`. However, I am ending up with an empty folder for this specific code (I am unable to apply my function to this code).

Below is my code:

```
import os
with open('list.txt') as list:
    for line in list:
        code =line.strip('\n')
        try:
            os.mkdir(code)
        except:
            continue
        ncbiSeq(code)
```

NB: This is my first time using `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear from its name, but the `continue` keyword means "go to the next iteration of the loop". So, when you get your exception, you won't run the `ncbiSeq(code)` line.

If you change it to `pass` instead (which is simply a python line that does nothing), I think your program will work as expected.

Comment: I replaced continue with pass. My function ran for code1 but for the second iteration, it gave this error: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'code2/code2_transcripts.txt'

Answer (score 1):

Use `pass` instead of `continue`. `continue` ignores the rest of the current iteration and starts another one. You are ignoring your function call and starting a new iteration. `pass`, instead, just does nothing. It explicitly tells the interpreter that there is nothing missing, you **really** don't want to do anything there.

Comment: I replaced `continue` with `pass`. My function ran for code1 but for the second iteration, it gave this error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'code2/code2_transcripts.txt'

Comment: @BioGeek Does that path exist? Is that the second line in list.txt?

Comment: This is the second line in list.txt. The path does not exisit. I want to create it and store the file I created in it.

Comment: @BioGeek You want to create the directory. Does the file already exist? If not, you need to create it. If it does, you need to move it into the new directory.